# How to secure an Angular SPA Website?

Tags: javascript, performance, security, angularjs, single-page-application

my development team are starting on an SPA web page which consumes data via WebAPI only. Here are the technologies that are supposed to be used on the site:

1. AngularJS - for SPA
2. Bearer Token - backend security

I have done my homework and checked several ways to secure the pages and one is (1) Have a mainController that communicate to the backend to authenticate the user and if valid, navigate to the intended page, but reroute otherwise. But the main concern here is the chatiness/rountrip of communication on every action - thousands of calls will be authenticating to the server.

(2) Another suggested way is to have a setInterval() calls that validate the session of the user from time to time - once he/she has been logged in. I think I have observed this behavior on Bank websites.

Can you suggest of other ways, if you have any?

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote on my question? Is there something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps downvoted as it could be construed as opinion based? Not that I agree, seems a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making an SPA, so I assume everything you want to secure (your *data*) is delivered through your WebAPI, and you can consider your Angular templates public.

In that case, you can basically ignore authentication on the client side, and just authenticate calls to the WebAPI.  Any server calls that are unauthenticated, unauthorised, or from an expired session return an HTTP 401, to which your Angular can respond to by redirecting to the login page.  You can use an HTTP Interceptor to simplify that code (example here stolen from [here](http://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/)).

```
myapp.factory('myHttpResponseInterceptor',['$q','$location',function($q,$location){
  return {
    response: function(response){
      return promise.then(
        function success(response) {
        return response;
      },
      function error(response) {
        if(response.status === 401){
          $location.path('/signin');
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else{
          return $q.reject(response); 
        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
//Http Intercpetor to check auth failures for xhr requests
myapp.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpResponseInterceptor');
}]);
```

In addition, if you know that your server-side session timeout is set to 20 mins, then you can also use an HTTP interceptor to keep track of the time of your last HTTP request.  When it gets to, say, 19 minutes ago, then you can warn the user that they will be logged off in 1 minute unless they respond, in which case you call a "keep alive" service to reset the timeout, else at 20 minutes redirect to the session expired page.  So no need to poll.

For a slightly better user experience, upon each view-load you could perform some rudimentary client-side check for the presence of a session cookie.  If it doesn't exists (eg. they've landed from a deep-link) then you can immediately redirect to login without calling the server.  If it does exist, proceed as normal, knowing the first call to WebAPI will validate it.

Comment: Hi Mike

"..just authenticate calls to the WebAPI"
 -> Oh I now understand, this is an inverse of what I mentioned on theproblem description above. Now resources (including pages) are to be checked on the backend INSTEAD of (1) Ajax call first (2) Return allow=true flag (3) re-call the orignial route call. Total of 3 round trips

"..an expired session return an HTTP 401"
 -> The interceptor just checks for invalid calls then return a 401, then if 401, returns to the login page
-> If the user is routed to login, shouldn't he/she still be able to browse the page where's he's allowed?

Comment: To clarify: 1. *Any* user (authorised or not) can request *any* Angular route. 2. The view will render and its controller will begin to run.  At this point the user may be able to see the content of the view, but as far as security goes this is OK, as views themselves do not contain sensitive data. (It is not so good in terms of UX, but there are simple workarounds.) 3. The controller now makes a server call to fetch data. 4. The server sees that the user is not authorised to view this data so returns a 401. 5. Angular abandons the partially rendered view and shows the login view instead.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct on the _any_ part. On the part where the view is already showing even when the ajax call isn't complete, top of my head, I know that there's really a solution for this, so I guess this is not a problem. on items 3 to 5, all is clear. :) Thanks for helping me out. If you can drop some basic to advanced resources regarding this, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

you can use cookie based authentication as you normally use, with token based on the cookie in request for CSRF, and clean up both on cookie expired, only thing to add here is response handling side of angluarjs where if auth error occurs, whole page refreshes. there is not much to be change on server side if you are already using some kind of authetication and csrf.

Comment: Hi iamgopal, thanks for your input regarding this. But unfortunately, cookie based auth is not the direction that we are heading right now. The backend people mentioned the term, Bearer Token type of authentication on the C# backend.